# TypeError: valores.reduce is not a function

Tags: javascript, react

Preciso fazer uma soma dos valores de vários objetos de dentro de uma lista.

Para isso, fiz um map percorrer a minha lista e defini que se o objeto tiver a propriedade true ele deve fazer um reduce de todos esses objetos e soma-los.

Porém ao terminar me deparo com:

> ```
> TypeError: valores.reduce is not a function
> ```

Como posso resolver isso?

```
import React, { Component, } from 'react'
import {Table } from 'react-bootstrap'

import {consultarExtrato} from '../../services/Extrato/index'
            
let saldo = window.localStorage.getItem('saldo');

class Teste extends Component   {
    
    

    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            //Array que recebe os Itens da API
            transacoes: [],     
        }   
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        consultarExtrato().then(dados => this.setState({transacoes: dados}))  
    }

    
    
    render() {
        return (
            
        <div>
            {
            //Tabela com os dados
            }
           <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
            <tbody>
                { 
                  this.state.transacoes.map((item)  => {
                    
        
                          var valores = item.valor

                          if(item.credito){

                           function sum(acc, val){
                               return acc + val
                           }

                           let resposta = valores.reduce(sum)
                           
                            return (
                                
                            <td>{resposta}</td>
                                
                               )
                          }

                         })
                }
            </tbody>
            </Table> 
        </div>
        )
    }
    
}

export default Teste;
```

Comment: o que tem dentro de transacoes?

Comment: Dentro de transacoes existe um array com diversos objetos, este é o link dele:  https://gitlab.com/desafio-conta-simples/developer/-/blob/master/mocks/transacoes.json

Comment: No caso novic eu quero somar somente os que são igual a true.

Comment: `valores.reduce(sum)` não é um `array`! e por isso da mensagem de erro, ele é uma chave de cada item, ou seja, não é ai que faz isso?

Comment: Estou pesquisando uma solução, realmente não é ai. Agora estou tentando fazer um map em transacoes, pegar os valores dos objetos, colocar esses valores dentro de um novo array, reduzir esse array e depois usar o reduce dentro do array reduzido. Será que funciona?

Comment: Fiz essa mudança Novic, inseri os valores dentro de um array e fiz a redução e depois a soma, mas quando imprimo meu resultado no console.log, eu não obtenho a soma, mas sim os valores do array anterior, sem serem somados.

Comment: toquinho se quer imprimir os dados e no final mostrar a soma?

Comment: Eu preciso imprimir a soma dos valores dos objetos que são iguais a true na API.  @novic

Comment: Não preciso imprimir os dados, só mostrar o valor final da soma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa mostrar a soma, então, precisa fazer igual o Javascript faz com o método `reduce` onde sua sintaxe padrão:

```
array.reduce(callback( acumulador, valorAtual[, index[, array]] )[, valorInicial]))
```

ref. [JavaScript Demo: Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Demonstrando um exemplo bem simples:

```js
const lista = [
  {valor: 100},
  {valor: 200},
  {valor: 50},
  {valor: 110},
  {valor: 160},
  {valor: 200},
];

const soma = lista.reduce((a,b) => a + b.valor, 0);
console.log(soma);
```

No código da sua pergunta que é feito pela biblioteca [react](/questions/tagged/react) é da seguinte forma:

```js
class Teste extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {            
            transacoes: [], 
            soma: 0
        }   
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      const dados = [
      {
        "empresaId": 1,
        "dataTransacao": "2020-09-01T09:50:00",
        "valor": 5000.0,
        "finalCartao": null,
        "tipoTransacao": "TED_IN",
        "descricaoTransacao": "Transferencia recebida",
        "estabelecimento": null,
        "credito": true,
    },
    {
        "empresaId": 1,
        "dataTransacao": "2020-09-01T10:50:00",
        "valor": 5000.1,
        "finalCartao": null,
        "tipoTransacao": "SLIP_IN",
        "descricaoTransacao": "Deposito por Boleto",
        "estabelecimento": null,
        "credito": true,
    },
    {
        "empresaId": 1,
        "dataTransacao": "2020-09-01T19:50:00",
        "valor": 159.99,
        "finalCartao":"0122",
        "tipoTransacao": "CARD",
        "descricaoTransacao": "Compra com cartão de crédito",
        "estabelecimento": "FACEBOOK",
        "credito": false,
    },

      ];
      this.setState({transacoes: dados}, 
        () => this.calcularSoma(true)
      );
    }   
    calcularSoma(credito) {
      const soma = this.state.transacoes
        .reduce((a,b) => {
          if (b.credito === credito) {
            return a + b.valor
          }
          return a;
        }, 0);
      this.setState({soma});
    }
    render() {
        return (            
          <div>Soma: {this.state.soma}</div>
        )
    }    
}

ReactDOM.render( <Teste/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Ao setar o estado para `transacoes` foi criado uma função para atualizar o estado da variável soma como do trecho abaixo:

```
this.setState({transacoes: dados}, 
    () => this.calcularSoma(true) // executado depois de atualizar transacoes
);
```

e no método `calcularSoma` com ***parâmetro*** `credito` para `verdadeiro` ou `falso` com `reduce`:

```
calcularSoma(credito) {
  const soma = this.state.transacoes
    .reduce((a,b) => {
      if (b.credito === credito) {
        return a + b.valor
      }
      return a;
    }, 0);
  this.setState({soma});
}
```

esse exemplo é que deve adaptar ao seu código.

Comment: Obrigado Novic! Funcionou perfeitamente.